# SQL Encontrar el tiempo total de falla, tomando filas consecutivas y sumar el tiempo

Tags: sql-server

Existe un proceso que cada 30 segundos envía un pulso para validar si el servicio está activo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En caso de ser exitoso me devuelve 0 en la columna MonitorEstado, en caso de presentar una falla devuelve el código de la falla.

Necesito agrupar en una todas las filas de falla para sumar el tiempo total de denegación de servicio, y si es mayor a 5 minutos poner un flag de incidente, y se es menor a 5 segundos poner incidencia.

En la tabla adjunto por ejemplo cada necesitaria agrupar todas lso codigos 10, sumar la cantidad de segundos, esto en un monitoreo de 24hrs y multiples plataformas, intente usando Lead, pero ya cuando tengo más de uno no me retorna el resultado que debria ser:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ES decir, esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con cada cambio de MonitorEstado se debe como hacer un reset, fue una intermitencia, no una falla.

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: Hola Arriel, estaba intentando primero hacer un Rank() usando de partición, Código de app, Fecha Inicio, Hora Inicio, Monitor Cod, ordenándolo por hora inicio), ya que la dificulta esta en que los códigos deben ser consecutivos es decir si tengo un 00 luego obtengo e códigos 10 seguidos, y luego otro 00, estos deben agrupar esos 3 códigos 10, como una interrupción seguida, ya que no precisamente es una falla, puede ser una interrupción de red

Comment: Lo que intentaste y los errores que encontraste, van EN la pregunta. El código relevante va EN la pregunta. Puedes editarla todas las veces que haga falta usando el enlace Editar que está bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas. Como has podido ver, sin info completa sólo verás en las respuestas a personas adivinando.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para lograr el resultado con base a la imagen, se genero un agrupamiento utilizando DENSE_RANK(), basado en la hora y monitor estado, esta opción permitió
contar con la columna OrdenMonitorEstado, la cual fue la base para calcular valores mínimos y máximos sobre los cuales se calcula la diferencia en segundos, para luego darle formato.

```
create table MONITOR 
(
  ID_Monitor                int IDENTITY (1,1),
  AplicacionCodigo          varchar (6), 
  AmbientesCodigo           varchar (10), 
  CanalCodigo               varchar (4), 
  MonitorinicioFecha        varchar(10), 
  MonitorinicioHora         time, 
  MonitorFinalFechaRevision varchar(10), 
  MonitorFinalHoraRevision  time,  
  MonitorEstado             varchar(4)
)
```

```
insert into MONITOR (AplicacionCodigo
                    ,AmbientesCodigo
                    , CanalCodigo
                    , MonitorinicioFecha
                    , MonitorinicioHora
                    , MonitorFinalFechaRevision
                    , MonitorFinalHoraRevision
                    , MonitorEstado )
select  AplicacionCodigo
        ,AmbientesCodigo
        , CanalCodigo
        , MonitorinicioFecha
        , MonitorinicioHora
        , MonitorFinalFechaRevision
        , MonitorFinalHoraRevision
        , MonitorEstado 
from
(

             select  2204 AplicacionCodigo, 'PRD' AmbientesCodigo,101 CanalCodigo,'25/11/2020' MonitorinicioFecha, '0:00:26'MonitorinicioHora, '25/11/2020' MonitorFinalFechaRevision, '0:00:27' MonitorFinalHoraRevision, '0'  MonitorEstado
    union all select 2204 ,'PRD', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:00:57', '25/11/2020', '00:00:58', 0
    union all select 2204 ,'PRD', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:01:28', '25/11/2020', '00:01:29', 0
    union all select 2204 ,'PRD', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:02:00', '25/11/2020', '00:02:01', 0
    union all select 2204 ,'PRD', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:02:32', '25/11/2020', '00:02:33', 10
    union all select 2204 ,'PRD', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:03:03', '25/11/2020', '00:03:05', 10
    union all select 2204 ,'PRD', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:03:35', '25/11/2020', '00:03:36', 10
    union all select 2204 ,'PRD', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:04:07', '25/11/2020', '00:04:09', 10
    union all select 2204 ,'PRD', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:04:39', '25/11/2020', '00:04:40', 0
    union all select 2204 ,'PRD', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:05:11', '25/11/2020', '00:05:13', 0
    union all select 2204 ,'PRO', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:05:43', '25/11/2020', '00:05:45', 40
    union all select 2204 ,'PRO', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:06:15', '25/11/2020', '00:06:17', 40
    union all select 2204 ,'PRD', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:06:47', '25/11/2020', '00:06:48', 40
    union all select 2204 ,'PRD', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:07:18', '25/11/2020', '00:07:20', 0
    union all select 2204 ,'PRD', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:07:50', '25/11/2020', '00:07:51', 0
    union all select 2204 ,'PRD', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:08:21', '25/11/2020', '00:08:24', 0
    union all select 2204 ,'PRD', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:08:54', '25/11/2020', '00:08:55', 0
    union all select 2204 ,'PRD', 101 ,'25/11/2020', '00:09:25', '25/11/2020', '00:09:27', 10
)t
```

```
with cteMonitor as
(
    select DENSE_RANK() over (order by  minGrpDate) OrdenMonitorEstado  
          ,AplicacionCodigo,  AmbientesCodigo,           CanalCodigo,              MonitorinicioFecha
          ,MonitorinicioHora, MonitorFinalFechaRevision, MonitorFinalHoraRevision, MonitorEstado
    from ( select        
             AplicacionCodigo          ,AmbientesCodigo           ,CanalCodigo               ,MonitorinicioFecha 
            ,MonitorinicioHora         ,MonitorFinalFechaRevision ,MonitorFinalHoraRevision  ,MonitorEstado
            ,MIN(MonitorinicioHora) over (partition by MonitorEstado,grp)  minGrpDate           
           from (       
                select   AplicacionCodigo,  AmbientesCodigo,           CanalCodigo,              MonitorinicioFecha
                        ,MonitorinicioHora, MonitorFinalFechaRevision, MonitorFinalHoraRevision, MonitorEstado
                        ,ROW_NUMBER() over (order     by  MonitorinicioHora, MonitorEstado)
                        -
                        ROW_NUMBER() over  (partition by  MonitorEstado order by MonitorinicioHora)  grp
                from MONITOR)t 
         )s
)select   OrdenMonitorEstado, AplicacionCodigo,          AmbientesCodigo,          CanalCodigo, MonitorinicioFecha
         ,MonitorinicioHora,  MonitorFinalFechaRevision, MonitorFinalHoraRevision, MonitorEstado
        , RIGHT('0' + CAST( DifSegs   / 3600     as varchar),2) + ':' 
        + RIGHT('0' + CAST((DifSegs   / 60) % 60 as varchar),2) + ':' 
        + RIGHT('0' + CAST( DifSegs   % 60       as varchar),2)DifSegs      
from
(   select  OrdenMonitorEstado, AplicacionCodigo,         AmbientesCodigo,           CanalCodigo,   MonitorinicioFecha
            ,MonitorinicioHora, MonitorFinalFechaRevision, MonitorFinalHoraRevision, MonitorEstado
            ,DATEDIFF ( SECOND,
                        MIN(MonitorinicioHora)        over (partition  by OrdenMonitorEstado order by  OrdenMonitorEstado)
                        ,
                        MAX(MonitorFinalHoraRevision) over (partition  by OrdenMonitorEstado order by   OrdenMonitorEstado)
                      )DifSegs
     from cteMonitor t
     group by OrdenMonitorEstado, AplicacionCodigo,          AmbientesCodigo,          CanalCodigo, MonitorinicioFecha
             ,MonitorinicioHora,  MonitorFinalFechaRevision, MonitorFinalHoraRevision, MonitorEstado
)t
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias, este me da un panorama de lo que estaba haciendo estaba malo... Garcais por tu Query me ayuda a tomar otro enfoque, este agrupa todos los resultados, digamos si a las 00:09:00 y 00:09:30 tuve un resultado 10 y estos se repiten tres veces pero a las 00:10:30 y 00:11:00 tuve un 00 ocupo agrupar como falla unicamente los ocurridos entre 00:09:00 y 00:10:30, el 00 reseteo el contador de falla o intermitencia

Comment: Para entender mejor lo que necesitas, edita tu pregunta con una tabla de muestra del escenario que planteas, y como espera que sea la respuesta, con eso podríamos hacer ajustes al script.

Comment: Si, pero. Sindespues viene otrs serie se MonitorCodigo conbvalor 0 los agrupa al segnento de arriba, no mosndejs separado...